# Postgres query all results from one table blended with conditional data from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 SQL tables and I'm trying to generate a new table with data from the 2 tables.
Jobs table:

```
jobs (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  position TEXT NOT NULL,
  location TEXT NOT NULL,
  pay NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  duration TEXT NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  term TEXT NOT NULL,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```

Applied table:

```
applied (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  completed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  job_id INTEGER REFERENCES jobs(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  UNIQUE (user_id, job_id)
);
```

The tabled populated with data look like this:
**Jobs table**
[image]

**Applied table**
[image]

I want my final query to be a table that matches the jobs table but that has a new column called `js_id` with true or false based on whether the user has applied to that job. I want the table to look like this:

[image]

Here is the query I came up with to generate the above table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (jobs.id) 
            jobs.*, applied.user_id as applicant,
           CASE WHEN applied.user_id = 1 THEN TRUE  
                ELSE FALSE END as js_id
        FROM jobs 
        JOIN applied on jobs.id = applied.job_id;
```

However this doesn't work as I add more applicants to the table. I get different `true` and `false` values and I haven't been able to get it working. When I remove `DISTINCT on (jobs.id)` my true values are consistent but I wind up with a lot more than the 3 jobs I want. Here are the results without the `DISTINCT on (jobs.id)`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
SELECT j.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from applied a
                where a.job_id = j.id and a.user_id = 1
       ) as js_id
FROM jobs j;
```